# How to path CSS file in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-staticfiles

When I access to this static file by just writing path after 'localserver:8000' is works but not working on html file. Even html loads image from image folder in static but CSS is in not applying on that html file. I am stuck for approximately 3 hours please help....

**SETTINGS.PY>INSTALLED_APPS**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'multiselectfield',
'shop',
'colorfield',
```

]

**STATC CODE**

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    STATICFILES_DIR = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
    MEDIA_URL = ''
    MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR
```

**HTML**

```
    {% load static %}
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/base-style.css' %}">
```

[image: IMAGE OF APP AND STATIC FOLDER]

Comment: I'm comparing your project to my own and it has only 2 differences, both in `settings.py`. Try removing the first `/` from `STATIC_URL` and commenting out the `STATICFILES_DIR` entirely. If that does not work, I cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

It solved by just restarting all apps.